# 3 free samples pricing rule in magento

Tags: magento, discount

I am trying to set up a pricing rule where customers can order up to three different sample products for free (100% discount).

All these sample products are belonging to the same category (category = samples). If a customer orders 4 or more different samples then the customer pays the normal price for the 4th, 5th, etc. product but still gets the first three for free.

I cannot manage to do this. I tried setting the Max Qty to 3 but this seems to only work if a customer would select 3 of the same product and not 3 different products.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Need for information to make a suitable answer. Database tables etc.

Comment: Have you tried tier pricing? I found this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-use-tier-pricing